# Python: Parse String as Date with Formatting

Tags: python, regex, date

A user can input a string and the string contains a date in the following formats `MM/DD/YY` or `MM/DD/YYYY`. Is there an efficient way to pull the date from the string? I was thinking of using RegEx for `\d+\/\d+\/\d+`. I also want the ability to be able to sort the dates. I.e. if the strings contain `8/17/15` and `08/16/2015`, it would list the 8/16 date first and then 8/17

Comment: Just checking - is `'1/1/2015'` a valid candidate? I used a bit more strict regex in my answer that expects zero-padded month and day parts.

Comment: I use \d+ because the date does not have to be zero padded. That date is acceptable

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation, I understood the MM/DD part too literally then (FWIW, I'll leave my answer as is, it's trivial to adjust the pattern anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), it's a built in function that knows how to create a datetime object from a string. It accepts a string to be converted and the [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) the date is written in.

```
from datetime import datetime

def str_to_date(string):
    pattern = '%m/%d/%Y' if len(string) > 8 else '%m/%d/%y'
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(string, pattern).date()
    except ValueError:
        raise  # TODO: handle invalid input
```

The function returns a [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) object which can be directly compared with other `date()` objects (e.g. when sorting) them.

Usage:

```
>>> d1 = str_to_date('08/13/2015')
>>> d2 = str_to_date('08/12/15')
>>> d1
datetime.date(2015, 8, 13)
>>> d2
datetime.date(2015, 8, 12)
>>> d1 > d2
True
```

#### Update

OP explained in a comment that strings such as `'foo 08/13/2015 bar'` should not be automatically thrown away, and that the date should be extracted from them.

To achieve that, we must first search for a candidate string in user's input:

```
import re
from datetime import date

user_string = input('Enter something')  # use raw_input() in Python 2.x

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}|\d{2})')  # 4 digits match first!
match = re.search(pattern, user_string)

if not match:
    d = None
else:
    month, day, year = map(int, match.groups())
    try:
        d = date(year, month, day)
    except ValueError:
        d = None  # or handle error in a different way

print(d)
```

The code reads user input and then tries to find a pattern in it that represents a date in `MM/DD/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YY` format. Note that the last capturing group (in parentheses, i.e. `()`) checks for either four or two consecutive digits.

If it finds a candidate date, it unpacks the capturing groups in the match, converting them to integers at the same time. It then uses the three matched pieces to tries to create a new `date()` object. If that fails, the candidate date was invalid, e.g. `'02/31/2015'`

Footnotes:

- the code will only catch the first date candidate in the input
- the regular expression used will, in its current form, also match dates in inputs like '12308/13/2015123'. If this is not desirable it would have to be modified, probably adding some lookahead/lookbehind assertions.

Comment: Hi @plamut , is it possible to have this also check for MM/DD and have it add current year automatically? I know I could just copy the code but I am certain there is an easier wayu

Comment: @Bijan Yes, it i possible, although you will need to change the regex a bit to only search for MM/DD part (and with an optional year part `/YY(YY)?`). And then, depending on the length of the match, you could either check if MM/DD represents a valid month/date pair, or (if len indicates that year is included, too) use the existing code.

Comment: Thanks! I got it by having the year be optional. If it does not exist, it adds the year automatically

Answer (score 3):

you could also try strptime:

```
import time

dates = ('08/17/15', '8/16/2015')

for date in dates:
    print(date)
    ret = None
    try:
        ret = time.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
    except ValueError:
        ret = time.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%y")
    print(ret)
```

---

**UPDATE**

update after comments:

this way you will get a valid date back or `None` if the date can not be parsed:

```
import time

dates = ('08/17/15', '8/16/2015', '02/31/15')

for date in dates:
    print(date)
    ret = None
    try:
        ret = time.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
    except ValueError:
        try:
            ret = time.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%y")
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print(ret)
```

---

**UPDATE** **2**

one more update after the comments about the requirements.

this is a version (it only takes care of the dates; not the text before/after. but using the regex group this can easily be extracted):

```
import re
import time

dates = ('foo 1 08/17/15', '8/16/2015 bar 2', 'foo 3 02/31/15 bar 4')

for date in dates:
    print(date)
    match = re.search('(?P<date>[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)', date)
    date_str = match.group('date')
    ret = None
    try:
        ret = time.strptime(date_str, "%m/%d/%Y")
    except ValueError:
        try:
            ret = time.strptime(date_str, "%m/%d/%y")
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print(ret)
```

Comment: Does it work with '02/31/15'? ;) The problem is that `ValueError` can also occur in the first `ValueError`'s except block...

Comment: raises `ValueError: day is out of range for month`. you could  also  catch that so `ret` will only be different from `None` if one of the tries to parse it  work...

Comment: IMO it would be more readable to only use a single `try..except` block, and you can detect which date format to use with an input string length check.

Comment: Well the thing is that the strings are not just `MM/DD/YY`, they contain text as well like `Some sample test, 8/31/15`

Comment: Of course, that's why we need to have a `try..catch` block in the first place to avoid having uncaught errors in the code. I was just suggesting that one such block is enough, no need to have two of them.

Comment: Well strptime does not like having other things in the string. i.e. I cant have `dates = ("Test string 08/31/2015")

Comment: Ah, I see now, thanks for clarifying. Didn't assume that inputs like `"foo 08/31/2015 bar"` should also be taken into consideration. In this case I would indeed use a regular expression to extract the date from the input (capturing days, months and a year) and then validate if these three together form a valid date. I'll update my suggestion.

Comment: Me too, seems like quite a few of us misunderstood the requirements.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `strptime` to store them as `datetime` objects. These objects can easily be compared and sorted that way.

```
import datetime
try:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime("08/03/2015", "%m/%d/%Y")
except:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime("08/04/15", "%m/%d/%y")
finally:
    dateList.append(date)
```

Note the difference between `%Y` and `%y`. You can then just compare dates made this way to see which ones are greater or less. You can also sort it using `dateList.sort()`

If you want the date as a string again you can use:

```
>>> dateString = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
>>> print dateString
'2015-08-03'
```

Comment: Breaks for '02/31/2015'... ;)

Comment: @plamut `if date.startswith("02/31"): sys.exit(1)` fixed :)

Comment: And then an unwary user inputs `'02/30/15'`... :)

Comment: This is perfect for me. I do not need substantial error checking.

Comment: @Bijan Are you 100% sure about that? Please double check so that you don't end up with any hidden bus in your code. :) But I'm glad we answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with regex when you can use  [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date [parser](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) from Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

timestr = ['8/8/95', '8/15/2014']
>>> [pd.datetools.parse(d) for d in timestr]
[datetime.datetime(1995, 8, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: This would require OP to install `pandas`. Seems like a bit of a stretch?
(unless OP is using `pandas` already, of course)

Comment: If you don't use Pandas, you don't know what you're missing... (-;]

Comment: True that, but I assumed OP does not use it, because it's not a default thing to use and it isn't mentioned anywhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using regex groups we'd get something like this:

```
import re
ddate = '08/16/2015'

reg = re.compile('(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)')
matching = reg.match(ddate)
if matching is not None:
    print(matching.groups())
```

Would yield

```
('08','16','2015')
```

You could parse this after, but if you wanted to get rid of leading 0's from the first place you could use

```
reg = re.compile('0*(\d+)\/0*(\d+)\/(\d+)')
```

Comment: This is incorrect, because it also "recognizes" dates such as `ddate = '02/31/2015'`, is not aware of leap years, etc.